# EF always generating initial schema

Tags: .net, entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first, database-schema

I have been using EF 4.3.1 with much success. Today though as I update one of the tables the whole schema is getting generated instead of only the updated for the single table.

How can I prevent the whole schema from generating?

I have seen this once or twice before and I usually just delete the file and run add-migration again and it seems fine.

Any ideas why this is happening.